# How to print negative value with currency

Tags: formatting, siunitx

At the moment my report print currency values with siunitx
with \$\numprint{12}
But negative values displayed as 
$-12.00

I would like to display it as:

-$12.00

Or you think $-12.00 is ok too for US ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How is the macro `\numprint` defined? (It doesn't seem to be a macro that's set up by the `siunitx` package.) On the ways of displaying negative amounts of money: There are a quite a few conventions out there, and they depend in part on the currency (`$`, `£`, or some other currency unit) in use. The `$-12.00` look is reminiscent of how some spreadsheets are set up for calculations with currencies. However, I do not think it's a common way of displaying negative amounts of dollars in running text. I honestly don't know if it's a common display form for other currency units.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use a negative sign with dollars, I would definitely put the negative sign before the dollar sign.

Here's a MWE which takes advantage of the fact that `siunitx` uses `expl3` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\aecompareTF#1#2#3{\fp_compare:nTF{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\aeabs#1{\fp_abs:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sisetup{%%
  group-separator={,},
  round-precision=2,
  round-mode=places,
  round-integer-to-decimal}

\def\mydollars#1{%%
  \aecompareTF{#1<0}
    {\SI{\aeabs{#1}}[-\$]{}}
    {\SI{#1}[\$]{}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \mydollars{12350.30}

  \mydollars{-12350.30}

 The effect of \verb`round-integer-to-decimal`: 

 \mydollars{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Mr. Ellett,
Thank you very much for your fast reply.
I'm using latex to generate PDF and it reports an error:
`( FP-ROUND ) ( FP-MUL ) ( FP-ROUND ) ( FP-DIV )
! Argument of \fp_compare_aux_v:w has an extra }.`
Is it possible to make changes for latex ? I tried to search myself, but there is very few information about fp_compare.

Comment: @Sergio My first thought is that perhaps you need to update to the most current version of LaTeX.  If the problem persists after updating, you might want to post a new question.

Comment: @sergio You can find information about the `expl3` code I've used by running `texdoc interface3`.